# Lint error building react-native (0.71.11) app with stripe

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

Got this error running `.\gradlew build`:

[Build Failed Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zr52.png)

This project is just created from termplate (npx react-native init) and cannot build after adding stripe-react-native package.

My package.json:
[package.json img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjAR6.png)

Parameters of build.gradle: 
`buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"`
`minSdkVersion = 21` 
`compileSdkVersion = 33` 
`targetSdkVersion = 33`

// We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
`ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"`

`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")`

gradle-wrapper.properties:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip`

Reading [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/Lint) documentation
I added this section of code in my android/app/build.gradle file:

`lint {` 
`quiet = true` 
`abortOnError = false` 
`disable += ['RestrictedApi','NewApi'] //tried this to fix` 
`checkReleaseBuilds = false` 
`ignoreWarnings = true` 
`baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")` 
`textReport = true` 
`ignore 'TypographyQuotes'` 
`ignoreTestSources true` 
`checkGeneratedSources true` 
`checkDependencies false` 
`}`

How to fix this error??

Comment: You may need to update your Gradle version in Android Studio. FWIW, these are only linting issues and shouldn't prevent the project from actually building.

Comment: You're right! But I would like to disable these messages configuring Lint ...  As i said i tried to add parameters to disable these type of errors but with no success. How can i do?